# Adding img dimension attributes into php code

Tags: php, image, attributes

I'm having a bit of issue adding image dimensions into my php code for my wordpress site. While I checked page speed through GTMetrix, they suggested me to add image dimensions specifically to increase page load time.

Here's the code line calling those images:

```
<div class="postdate">
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/**date.png**"  /> 
<?    php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> 
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/**folder.png**" /> 
<?php the_category(', ') ?> 
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/**comments.png**" /> 
<?php comments_popup_link('No Comments &#187;', '1 Comment &#187;', '% Comments &#187;'); ?> 
<?php if (current_user_can('edit_post', $post->ID)) { ?> 
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/**edit.png**" /> 
    <?php edit_post_link('Edit', '', ''); 
} ?>
</div>
```

I would like to be able to add the dimension Width= 16 and Height= 16 after each image (highlighted).

Please help out.

Regards, Imran.

Comment: apply a class to your `img` tags, and use CSS to specify those dimensions, have a read here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="postdate">
    <img width="16" height="16" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/**date.png**"  /> 
    <?    php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> 
    <img width="16" height="16" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/**folder.png**" /> 
    <?php the_category(', ') ?> 
    <img width="16" height="16" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/**comments.png**" /> 
    <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments &#187;', '1 Comment &#187;', '% Comments &#187;'); ?> 
    <?php if (current_user_can('edit_post', $post->ID)) { ?> 
        <img width="16" height="16" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/**edit.png**" /> 
    <?php edit_post_link('Edit', '', ''); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use CSS?

```
<style type="text/css">
    .postdate img { 
        width: 16px; 
        height: 16px;
     }
</style>
```